# TypeError: firebase_compat_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.default.auth is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

I'm trying to add authentication via firebase but it giving me an error saying

> TypeError: firebase_compat_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.default.auth is not a function

Here is all the code for authentication

```py
import Head from "next/head";

// var firebase = require("firebase");

import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/auth";

import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import Reddit from "../components/Reddit";

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "<api-key>",
  authDomain: "<auth-domain>",
  projectId: "<project-id>",
  storageBucket: "<storage-bucket>",
  messagingSenderId: "166670883433",
  appId: "1:166670883433:web:f24816c8fe909b0f89e0f8",
});

const auth = firebase.default.auth();

const [user] = useAuthState(auth);

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="h-screen bg-black text-white">
      <Head>
        <title>Reddit - Dive into anything!</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/logo.svg" />
      </Head>

      {user ? <Reddit /> : <SignIn />}
    </div>
  );
}

function SignIn() {
  const signInWithGoogle = () => {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Sign in with google</button>
    </div>
  );
}

// export default App;
```

Can anyone help me with this. Thanks!

Here's my Reddit.js

```js
import Trending from "./trending/Trending";

function Reddit() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Trending />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Reddit;
```

Here is my package.json file

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.6.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.5",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.1",
    "firebase": "^9.5.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.0",
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
    "postcss": "^8.3.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `package.json`?

Comment: yeah i just updated the problem please look at it again

Answer (score 8):

This line is causing you this problem.

```js
const auth = firebase.default.auth();
```

It seems that you are mixing the syntax between the v9 `Modular` and `Compat` libraries type.

##### By using the Modular library,

You can get it by using `getAuth` method from `firebase/auth`

Example:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

initializeApp({
 // Provide the app config
});

const auth = getAuth();
```

##### By using the Compat library,

`Compat` is a library to support the old SDK structure from v8.

Example:

```js
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";

firebase.initializeApp({
  // Provide the app config
});

const auth = firebase.auth();
```

Note: `firebase/compat/` in v9 provided a familiar API surface that is fully compatible with the v8 SDK but it will be removed in the future. So I encourage you to upgrade to use the new Modular API surface. [See more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade)

Note 2: I saw that you have the `firebase-admin` installed on your project. The `firebase-admin` shouldn't be installed in the Frontend since it is designed to be used to manage the Firebase project on the backend which required the highest permission on your Firebase project.

Comment: It now lets me in my website but when i click the login btn it gives me a runtime error saying: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'GoogleAuthProvider') please help

Comment: Actually, In v9 they have changed the entire API structure. To get the instance of `GoogleAuthProvider` you can follow [this tutorial from Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin)

Comment: I just updated my answer to show the example of using the `modular` and `compat` library in the SDK v9. Sorry if this caused confusion.

Comment: Oh yeah it works fine when i followed along with the documentation just forgot to tell sorry